# How do I enforce type checking for children of a class or interface?

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I asked a question yesterday that was probably a bit too broad, so this is my attempt to break it down. Link to that question here: [How to define an abstract model for use in an abstract service?](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66233565/how-to-define-an-abstract-model-for-use-in-an-abstract-service)

I define an abstract class `Model` with a private property `id`, a constructor, and a static method create. Then, I define an interface `ResponseBody`, which implementations of this `Model` class will extend. JSON data will come back from the server in the form of `DerivedClass.ResponseBody`, which the client will pass to `create` to form a new object derived from `Model`. Below is what I have to begin with.

```js
export abstract class Model {
  get id() {
    return this._id;
  }

  constructor(private _id: number) {}

  static create<T extends Model>(body: T.ResponseBody): T {
    console.error(
      "Static method create() must be defined by class implementing Model."
    );

    return undefined;
  }
}

export module Model {
  export interface ResponseBody {
    type?: "response-body";
    id: number;
  }
}
```

My issue here is defining the type of `body` parameter of `create`. I get an error: `'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.` I want to ensure that the type enforces that the correct values are passed to create, which will always contain an `id`, but must also contain whatever is defined in derived classes. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I think you can use an intersection type to achieve what you want

Comment: I'm not sure that you can extend a module in that way.  It's fine to do `Model.ResponseBody` but you cannot do `T.ResponseBody` because `T` is type and not a module (or a namespace).  There might be a better way to structure this whole thing based on your previous question.

Comment: My instinct is that you want to define your individual model types as classes which implement a shared interface.  Model would be a class that takes one of those classes in the constructor rather than being an abstract class that they extend.

Comment: You're doing a bunch of stuff that TypeScript doesn't support, and I'm not sure how to work around all of them without making a big mess. Right now TypeScript doesn't support *type families* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#17588](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17588)), *abstract static* methods (see [microsoft/TypeScript#34516](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34516)), or *static polymorphic `this`* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863)), all of which seem to be prerequisites for this approach.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/3NDb8W) work for you?  It refactors the abstract `Model` class to a function called `extendModel()` which requires its parameter to meet the constraints you can't really express with your approach.  If you think this could work for you I'll write up an answer; let me know.

Comment: @jcalz I'm disappointed by the limitations of the language, but your demo looks promising. I will try it.

Comment: @jcalz This works for the most part, but I'm having trouble adding methods to the class. Also, I have no idea how well it will work once I try to implement services (like in my original question), but one step at a time. I look forward to your answer.

Comment: "I'm having trouble adding methods to the class".  Methods like what and to which class?  Could you modify your example code to show what you're trying to do?

Comment: Never mind, I think I can take it from here. Just post your code as an answer and I'll accept it.